# useEffect-Hook : React Hook "useWeb3React()" cannot be called inside a callback

Tags: web3js, react

After inserting `const web3React = useWeb3React();` into my `App.js` component, I get the following error message.

> React Hook "useWeb3React" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.
> [image]

Code Snippet:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useWeb3React, Web3ReactProvider } from "@web3-react/core";
import Web3 from "web3";

import SmartContractManagementComponent from "./components/SmartContractManagementComponent";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import CreateContract from "./components/CreateContract";
import TransactionDashboard from "./components/TransactionDashboard";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import { WalletConnector } from "./components/wallet/WalletConnector";

const App = () => {
useEffect(() => {
    const web3React = useWeb3React();
  }, []);

  const getLibrary = (provider) => {
    return new Web3(provider);
  };

  return (

    <Web3ReactProvider getLibrary={getLibrary}>
      <div className='App'>
        <Navbar />
        <WalletConnector />
        <div className='flex flex-row w-full'>
          <CreateContract className='flex w-1/2' />
          <TransactionDashboard className='flex w-1/2' />
        </div>

        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Web3ReactProvider>
  );
};
```

Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong to access the `useWeb3React`-Hook? I thought it useful to call the hook just after the other components have been mounted so that MetaMask will already be injected.

Answer (score 1):

`useWeb3React()` cannot be called inside `useEffect` callback, or any callback. It needs to be top level inside the component. So it needs to be like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const web3React = useWeb3React();
...
}
```

which means you don't need `useEffect` for setting up `useWeb3React`.

You can also take the `getLibrary` function outside of the component since it only needs to be called once to get the library:

```
const getLibrary = (provider) => {
  return new Web3(provider);
};

const App = () => {
  const web3React = useWeb3React();
  return (
    <Web3ReactProvider getLibrary={getLibrary}>
     ...
    </Web3ReactProvider>
  );
}
```

If you want to wait until components have been mounted you can create a `hasMounted` boolean and update it to true inside `useEffect`. That way you have something to check against and verify components have mounted:

```
...

const App = () => {
  ...

  const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = React.useState(false)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setHasMounted(true)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {hasMounted && (
        <Web3ReactProvider getLibrary={getLibrary}>
          <div className='App'>
            ...
          </div>
        </Web3ReactProvider>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```